# Трансформировать массив в объект

Tags: javascript, node.js

Необходимо преобразовать массив в объект

Входные данные:

```
[
  {"product": "name1", "price": 1000, "amount": 3},
  {"product": "name2", "price": 1200, "amount": 5}
]
```

Желаемый результат:

```
{
  "name1": {"price": 1000, "amount": 3},
  "name2": {"price": 1200, "amount": 5}
 }
```

Comment: про `reduce` не читали?

Comment: ну я ищу примеры кода, нечего толком не найду ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {"product":"name1","price":1000,"amount":3},
  {"product":"name2","price":1200,"amount":5}
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.product] = {
    price: el.price,
    amount: el.amount,
  };
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**Полезные ссылки** 
[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: большое человеческое